# sub-threads of a thread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance

Assuming you have a multi-threading program, each thread may call a function from a DLL, and the function in that DLL will processing data in a multi-threading manner, in general, are there any peformance benefit/hit by doing this instead of make these functions in the DLL single-threaded?

Comment: it _can_ be beneficial, and it _can_ hurt.

Comment: It all depends on your programming design. Single threads are good if the tasks are menial, because you save yourself the trouble of synchronisation, threads are good if the tasks at hand are time intensive and the result doesn't really matter to the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not. It depends on many things.

Firstly, spawning new threads is pretty expensive, so the amount of work that will be done in parallel will need to offset this cost.

Secondly, there need to be spare CPU cycles for those threads to actually run in parallel, and not be time-sliced onto the same core.

Lastly, the threads will need to be able to use those spare CPU cycles and not, for example, spend most of their time waiting for each other.

Comment: Forgot to mention they can be useful to simplify design e.g. GUI applications.

Comment: @EdHeal: That's a good point. However, I think this question is about data crunching (OP says "processing data", "peformance benefit" etc).

Comment: Can also be true for data processing. just because you have multiple threads can mean that some are in a hibernated state.